# resolve DNS with specific DNS server

Tags: security, dns

I want to manually set/resolve DNS with specific DNS server, would that be possible somehow with `<link>` tags? my guessing is no, but why can't it be done?

I know there is this `rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://example.com"`
but why can't I manually set it and use something like:

```
<!-- use a specific server for example.com -->
<link rel="dns-resolve" href="example.com" value="31.139.62.106">
```

or with ajax do the following:

```
fetch('https://31.139.62.106/api/', {
  headers: {
    Host: 'example.com'
  }
})
```

`host` is listed as one of the [forbidden request header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) at MDN. But why is it forbidden? What harm could it do?

For me it's just one of those historical reasoning made up in the 90s that I can't find the answer to... or I'm too stupid to figure out why... ‍♂️

Not being able to specify it seems to do more harm to my own privacy.

---

**Reason / background:** I built a service today and used one of those public available WebSocket trackers built by some supporting WebTorrent developers out there.

(all doe it's completely unrelated to torrent stuff. Just used theres websocket trackers to match WebRTC peers for something other totally legit I have built).

I decided to try it out on a public municipality wifi hotspot today and found out that `tracker.example.com` was blocked by my ISP or some Router config. It must have been based on the domain name and not by ip address cuz later i found out that `example.com` was working and `tracker.example.com` did not. Both top & sub domain had the same ip address but I could surf to `example.com` but not `tracker.example.com` (same applied to 3 other public trackers)

To me it indicates that they are just snooping around at what I'm doing on there wifi and blocking any domain that starts with `tracker`. The message i got was something in lines with "blocked b/c copyright/privacy reason bla bla bla" - i can understand why but that is just so annoying!

After that i started lookin into dns over https - got to try it if that might solve it for the next time I visit the public wifi next week.

Comment: "why can't I manually set it and use something like" Because it creates immediately a huge can of worn. What if a websiteA has such a link for websiteB but not with its true address, but another one? Do you think it is a good idea that a local cache for the DNS is completely available to be changed by any remote webserver you consult? New versions of browsers rely more and more on DNS over HTTPS which might help you in your specific case. Otherwise just use a VPN if you are inside an hostile network...

Comment: You are right about cache. Would not be such a good thing to set Google to my own ip address cache it and then have them navigate to Google. But it wouldn't have to cache it. It could just be true for my own domain? And what about my ajax request? It would not have to look up any dns or use anything from cache when i manually specified a ip address. None the less i think it could be useful for load balancing

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: "None the less i think it could be useful for load balancing" ??? DNS does load balancing by default so you already have the feature. Also, imagine your host change its IP address... now in in your system you have to manually change all HTML pages having hardcoded the IP address...

Comment: not if you have a dynamic html page generated by eg: backend